# How to let the back end to know that the access token sent by user is valid

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to create a website for admin login in add data to the database. Actually I have already write an API for admin when they login to the web. An access token will be generated by jwt, pass to front end and save to users' local store. I know the jwt can be added in user req's header.

But how to let the back end to know that the access token sent by user is valid?

In my db, I have a user table that save the users' email and hashed password. Is it a good way for back end to decode the access token to get the user's email and search the db when user call the API with the headers?

This part of my Lambda function for login to the web:

```
const { JWT_SECRET } = process.env
            const accessToken = jwt.sign(
              { username: event.username },
              JWT_SECRET,
              { expiresIn: '7days' }
            )
```

also in my db. the data structure is:

```
{
  'email": "***",
  "id": "*",
  "password": "***",
  "username": "***"
}
```

In front end, let say there are an API to send a new data:

```
export const addNewData = function (accessToken, newValue) {
  return apiClient.post(***API endpoint***',
    newValue, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
      }
    })
```

Comment: You can just decode the jwt token in the backend to check its validity. You can create the token in such a way that it contains some unique data from the user like user Id. Then you can use that user Id to get the user data.

Comment: Can you put some code here what you just did for it??

Comment: @RajarshiDas I've add some of my code

Answer (score 0):

The best way to validate the users is to use middleware, Below is a sample snippet for logging a user and validating the user using middleware.

```
const auth = require("../middleware/auth");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const _ = require("lodash");
const { User, validate } = require("../models/user");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = validate(req.body);
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

  let user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
  if (user) return res.status(400).send("User already registered.");

  user = new User(_.pick(req.body, ["name", "email", "password"]));
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);
  await user.save();

  const token = user.generateAuthToken();
  res
    .header("x-auth-token", token)
    .header("access-control-expose-headers", "x-auth-token")
    .send(_.pick(user, ["_id", "name", "email"]));
});
```

Here is the middleware to verify the user token from the custom header.

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const config = require("config");

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  const token = req.header("x-auth-token");
  if (!token) return res.status(401).send("Access denied. No token provided.");

  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get("jwtPrivateKey"));
    req.user = decoded;
    next();
  } catch (ex) {
    res.status(400).send("Invalid token.");
  }
};
```

Here is the snippet for using the middleware to authenticate the user before retrieving the user profile data.

```
router.get("/me", auth, async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findById(req.user._id).select("-password");
  res.send(user);
});
```

Comment: I am sorry ,but I dont know how to add middleware in AWS lambda...